# Find an item in a list using the known index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm having trouble with Python here and need your help.

I want to return an item found at a particular index. I can't know what the item is yet, only the index.  Everything I have found is the opposite of what I need, i.e., find the index of a known item using `myList.index(item)`.

Snippet:

```
new_lst = x
new_lst.sort()
leng = len(new_lst).....

    elif leng > 1 and leng % 2 == 0:
    a = (leng / 2) #or float 2.0
    b = a - 1 
    c = new_lst.index(a) #The problem area
    d = new_lst.index(b) #The problem area
    med = (c + d) / 2.0
    return med ......
```

The above will only return if `a` is in `new_lst`.  Else it errors out.  I want to get the middle two numbers (if list is even), add them together and then average them.

Example: `new_lst = [4,3,8,8]`. Get em, sort em, then should take the middle two numbers (`a` & `b` above, indices 1 & 2), add them and average: `(4 + 8) / 2` equaling 6.  My code would assign 2 to `a`, look for it in the list and return an error: 2 not in `new_lst`.  Not what I want.

Comment: I also want to mention, that the line `new_lst = x` is not making a copy of the list, it's only creating a second reference. If you need to make a copy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python. My preference is the `copy` package, since it's nice and explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the `list.index` function - this is for finding the position of an item in a list. To find the item at a position, you should use slicing (which, in other languages, is sometimes called "indexing", which is probably what confused you). Slicing a single element out of an iterable looks like this: `lst[index]`.

```
>>> new_lst = [4, 3, 8, 8]
>>> new_lst.sort()
>>> new_lst
[3, 4, 8, 8]

>>> if len(new_lst) % 2 == 0:
    a = new_lst[len(new_lst)//2-1]
    b = new_lst[len(new_lst)//2]
    print((a+b)/2)

6.0
```

Comment: Thanks all and esp thanks to @senshin !  That is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find!

Answer (score 2):

You reference an item in a list by using square brackets, like so

```
c = new_lst[a]
d = new_lst[b]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return an item found at a particular index.

Do you want to use the `[]` operator?

`new_lst[a]` gets the item in `new_lst` at index `a`.

See [this documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) for more on the subject.